# Can properties that are read-only to code outside of an object be created in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

In JavaScript, can there exist properties that are such that they can only be modified by the code inside of the object it is attached to and is read-only and protected from deletion by code outside of its object?

Comment: You can use a custom setter to deny the ability to modify a property value, but without Symbol support it's somewhat hard to make it 100% secure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one possibility is to use the revealing module pattern - keep the variables that you want to keep private and unalterable inside the module, and expose a getter that returns that variable. See comments:

```js
const counter = (() => {
  let num = 5;
  return {
    get num() { return num },
    increment: () => num++,
  };
})();
console.log(counter.num); // 5
counter.num++; // Won't do anything, since num can only be changed from the inside
console.log(counter.num); // Still 5
counter.increment(); // Calls the method internal to the object, which increments num
console.log(counter.num); // 6
```